# UICollectionView functions not found using Swift in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My app defined a class and gets `error: reloadData() not found` in self.collectionView.reload(). Other UICollectionView functions are also not found. It seems to get confused for the two collectionView functions below. How can I fix this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //fetch the photos from collection
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
    self.photosAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)

    self.collectionView.reloadData()   // error: '(UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'reloadData'
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{ ...}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{...}
```

Comment: Notice that CollectionView and collectionView are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

to

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

and it should work!